# Storing userdata in $_SESSION vs. repeated DB accesses

Tags: php, mysql, session

There is certain userdata read from the (MySQL) database that will be needed in subsequent page-requests, say the name of the user or some preferences.

Is it beneficial to store this data in the $_SESSION variable to save on database lookups?

We're talking (potentially) lots of users. I'd imagine storing in $_SESSION contributes to RAM usage (very-small-amount times very-many-users) while accessing the database on every page request for the same data again and again should increase disk activity.

Comment: Session data by default is stored on disk. While it is distributing load from the database, you are still going to have a bit of a disk io with session data stored in that location. You may want to look at using memcached as good option.

Comment: the database probably won't access the disk (again) as the record is already in the memory.

Comment: @Karoly: so it's best to store nothing in $_SESSION that is already saved in the DB and just repeatedly read from the DB in hope it's already in the memory?

Comment: you have to test it, but if it's a single query, then you won't gain much... if it's a couple queries, then it's worth caching it in a K-V store, but then you have to build the logic in the app to update the cache if the values change...

Answer (score 2):

The irony of your question is that, for most systems, once you get a large number of users, you need to find a way to get your sessions out of the default on-disk storage and into a separate persistence layer (i.e. database, in-memory cache, etc.).  This is because at some point you need multiple application servers, and it is usually a lot easier not to have to maintain state on the application servers themselves.

A number of large systems utilize in-memory caching (memcached or similar) for session persistence, as it can provide a common persistence layer available to multiple front-end servers and doesn't require long time persistence (on-disk storage) of the data.

Well-designed database tables or other disk-based key-value stores can also be successfully used, though they might not be as performant as in-memory storage. However, they may be cheaper to operate depending on how much data you are expecting to store with each session key (holding large quantities of data in RAM is typically more expensive than storing on disk).

Understanding the size of session data (average size and maximum size), the number of concurrent sessions you expect to support, and the frequency with which the session data will need to be accessed will be important in helping you decide what solution is best for your situation.

Comment: Oh, wow. This is ... so much more complicated then I'd anticipated. Thanks nontheless!

Comment: @Marcos It is not really that complex.  The first thing I would say is to do a rough estimate of the storage size needed.  You can determine this be calculating `average_session_storage_size (bytes) x number_of_sessions_utilized (#/per second) x session_expiration_limit (seconds)`. This will yield a size in bytes that you need to support.  If this number is relatively small (< a few MB's), then you could easily allocate the necessary RAM on a moderately sized server (or cluster of small servers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple storage backends for session data in PHP. Per default its saved to files. One file for one session. You can also use a database as session backend or whatever you wan't by implementing you own [session save handler](http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

If you want your application most scalable I would **not** use sessions on file system. Imagine you have a setup with mutiple web servers all serving your site as a farm. When using session on filesystem a user had to be redirected to the same server for each request because the session data is only available on that servers filesystem. If you not using sessions on filesystem it would not matter which server is being used for a request. This makes the load balancing much easier.

Instead of using session on filesystem I would suggest

- use cookies
- use request vars across multiple requests

or (if data is security critical)

- use sessions with a database save handler. So data would be available to each webserver that reads from the database (or cluster).

Comment: both of these are not secure (the user can send arbitrary data), so the use case is quite limited...

Answer (score 0):

Using sessions has one major drawback: You cannot serve concurrent requests to the user if they all try to start the session to access data. This is because PHP locks the session once it is started by a script to prevent data from getting overwritten by another script. The usual thinking when using session data is that after your call to `session_start()`, the data is available in `$_SESSION` and will get written back to the storage after the script ends. Before this happens, you can happily read and write to the session array as you like. PHP ensures this will not destroy or overwrite data by locking it.

Locking the session will kill performance if you want to do a Web2.0 site with plenty of Ajax calls to the server, because every request that needs the session will be executed serially. If you can avoid using the session, it will be beneficial to user's perceived performance.

There are some tricks that might work around the problem:

1. You can try to release the lock as soon as possible with a call to `session_write_close()`, but you then have to deal with not being able to write to the session after this call.
2. If you know some script calls will only read from the session, you might try to implement code that only reads the session data without calling `session_start()`, and avoid the lock at all.
3. If I/O is a problem, using a Memcache server for storage might get you some more performance, but does not help you with the locking issue.
4. Note that the database also has this locking issue with all data it stores in any table. If your DB storage engine is not wisely chosen (like MyISAM instead of InnoDB), you'll lose more performance than you might win with avoiding sessions.

All these discussions are moot if you do not have any performance issues at all right now. Do whatever serves your intentions best. Whatever performance issues you'll run into later we cannot know today, and it would be premature optimization (which is the root of evil) trying to avoid them.

Always obey the first rule of optimization, though: Measure it, and see if a change improved it.